# PHP Making a basic product search form

Tags: php, arrays, forms, search, product

So I have been working on this thing for a while and am stuck. Basically I currently have an excel sheet with 2 basic colmns the first has a list of old products and the 2nd column has the new product that replaces them. I have been working to setup a simple php site where I can type the Old product in and it will state the replacment. I started out by using arrays where I set the array as the product and all of the keys in the array are the various old products and it looks like this:

```
$search = $_POST["search"];
$newprod = array("prod1", "prod2", "prod3");

echo "You searched for the $search<BR>";
echo "This can be replace with these:";

if (in_array("$search", $newprod)) {
    echo "NewProdName";
}
```

So this worked fine when I used it for a few different products but on the products that have long lists of old products the server doesn't like the array having too many keys so it just stops reading it and gives an error for the page. Is there a better way or doing this. I know there is a better more complex way I am just wanting this to be a simple thing that i can figure out and expand on later when I am better with php.

Comment: doesn't like having too many keys? how many does it have?

Comment: Don't you know how to use a database? That's definitely the way to go.

Comment: I disagree w/ PRR for what its worth. If you can fit it all into memory, I think a csv file is fine and should be quite fast. What error is it giving though?

Comment: I just retyped it and it went so not sure why I was getting the error but I have this working if anyone knows a simpler way I am still open to help simplifying it. Thanks for the suggestions I will see if I can get csv going. Fairly new to php.

Comment: so the code you typed here wokrs well? and you have some source of data in excel sheet? you cpied that data to an array which not show to us and ask for solution with data source we haven't seen?  there are 2 ways: 1 - show us your data as it is in plain text (if it is less than 1000) and we can try to help, or use database

Comment: Kim I think I had described what I was doing perfectly I cannot show what I am converting because it is something I have signed confidentiality agreements that may apply to this. I even changed my code above slightly to say newprod and prod1 instead of what they actually are. what is in the data doesn't make a difference. Other people answered my question perfectly and I have it working now and am looking at either a database or csv file as were suggested earlier to make changing this in the future easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

You shouldn't put the variable in quotes.

```
if (in_array($search, $newprod)) {
    echo "NewProdName";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes from "search"

```
echo "You searched for the $search<BR>";
```

Would Become:

```
echo "You searched for the ".$search."<BR>";
```

And then

```
if (in_array("$search", $newprod)) {
```

Would Become:

```
if (in_array($search, $newprod)) {
```